# Lower dimensional Pin cobordisms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cobordism

I'm studying Pin cobordism groups of a point for some low dimensions. I found a general result by Anderson, Brown, Peterson in Theorem 5.1 of their paper "Pin cobordism and related topics" [http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?pid=comahe-002:1969:44::42](http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?pid=comahe-002:1969:44%3a:42). Using the Pontryagin-Thom construction, they are able to get the following results:

1) The contribution to $\Omega_{*}^{Pin}$ of terms $\pi_{*}(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty} \wedge \textbf{K}(\mathbb{Z}_2,n))$ is a direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in each dimension $\geq n$. 2) The contribution to $\Omega^{Pin}_*$ of terms $\pi_{*}(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty} \wedge \textbf{B}O \langle 8n \rangle)$ is as follows: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in dim$8n+i, i \equiv 0, 1(8)$; 0 in dim$8n+i, i\equiv 3, 4, 5, 7(8)$; $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{4k+3}}$ in dim$8n+8k+2, k\geq0$; and $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{4k+4}}$ in dim$8n+8k+6, k\geq0$. 3) The contribution to $\Omega^{Pin}_{*}$ of terms $\pi_{*}(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty} \wedge \textbf{B}O \langle 8n+2 \rangle)$ is as follows: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in dim$8n+2+i, i\equiv 1, 2, 5, 7(8)$; $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ in dim$8n+2+i, i\equiv6(8)$; 0 in dim$8n+2+i\equiv3(8)$; $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{4k+1}}$ in dim$8n+2+8k$, $k\geq0$; and $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{4k+2}}$ in dim$8n+2+8k+4$, $k\geq0$.

However, when I tried to apply the above theorem for some low dimensional cases, I get some apparent contradictions. For example, in dim=2, if we apply the above theorem, we get $\Omega^{Pin}_2 = \mathbb{Z}_8 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, which contradicts the known result of $\mathbb{Z}_8$. (Somehow by considering contributions only from $\pi_{*}(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty} \wedge \textbf{B}O \langle 8n \rangle)$ and ignoring all other contributions, one gets the correct results up to dimension 7.) Also, for dim=22, when applying this theorem, one gets $\Omega^{Pin}_{22} = \mathbb{Z}_{2^{12}} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^8} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^{10}} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^6} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^2}$, instead of $\Omega^{Pin}_{22} = \mathbb{Z}_{2^{12}} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^8} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^6} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, which is given as an example on page 467 of their paper.

Can anyone make sense of the above theorem?

Comment: Could you give a source for "known results"?

Comment: Yes. Kirby and Taylor give them up to dimension 4 http://math.berkeley.edu/~kirby/papers/Kirby%20and%20Taylor%20-%20Pin%20structures%20on%20low-dimensional%20manifolds%20-%20MR1171915.pdf

Comment: It looks like Anderson, Brown and Peterson say that the contribution of $\pi _*(RP^{\infty }\vee HZ/2)$ is either $Z/2$ or $0$ (and not $Z/2$), this takes care of the problem in dimension 2.

Comment: Well, the Z/2 here is from BO<8n+2>, which contributes $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{4k+1}}$ in dim 8n+2+8k. If you take n=k=0, you get Z/2.

Comment: I see.  I guess $\pi _2(RP^{\infty }\wedge kO<2>)$ (or do they really mean $BO<2>$ ?) can be computed easily without Adams SS, so this is probably the first thing to check.

Comment: It looks like by $BO<2>$ they mean $kO<2>$ (1-connective cover of the real $K$-theory {\it spectrum}, which also is denoted bo<2> in the litterature).  So $\pi _2(RP^{\infty }\wedge kO<2>)$ is actually $Z/2$.  This would mean that there is a contradiction between the paper http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970690?uid=3738016&uid=2481646813&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21104366205173 ( The structure of the Spin cobordism ring ) and the results of Kirby and Taylor.

Comment: I think you are right about the BO part. I'm a bit confused. Is the homotopy group of MSpin equal to the direct sum of homotopy groups of the three constituent parts? Theorem 1 of http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?pid=comahe-003:1990:65::32 computes the homotopy groups of $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ wedging with $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,n)$, $BO<8n>$, $BO<8n+2>$ respectively. And then follows Cor. 2 which says that the 1st and 2nd line of the 1st table gives you the Pin and Pin+ bordisms up to dim 7. Naively, one expects that the Pin and Pin+ groups should be the sum of tables 1 and 2, instead of table 1 alone.

Comment: So I think the Kirby and Taylor results are correct. Somehow, for dimensions 1-7, only BO<8n> is contributing to the pin groups. I don't know about higher dimensional cases. It would be interesting to know when and in what ways do the other 2 parts, especially BO<8n+2> contribute.

Comment: Yes,  they say that $MPin$ splits as a wedge ($\vee $) of spectra that are smash product ($\wedge $) of $\Sigma ^nHZ/2$ etc., with $RP^{\infty}$.  So the homotopy groups (or any generalized homology groups) of $MPin$ is a direct sum of those spectra.  On the other hand, what is not clear in the paper "Pin cobordism and related topics" is the number of summands $ko<8n>$'s and $ko<8n+2>$'s given $n$. This can be read off from "Structure of Cobordism ring" paper Theorem 2.2, and probably this will explain what happens in dimension 22.  But $BO<2>$ seems to be there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper "Pin cobordism and related topics" [http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?pid=comahe-002:1969:44::42](http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?pid=comahe-002:1969:44%3a:42). only gives the homotopy groups of 
$RP^{\infty }\wedge X$ where $X$ is either $\Sigma ^nHZ/2$, $bo\langle 8n\rangle$ and
$bo\langle 8n+2\rangle$, noting that they are summands of the homotopy groups of the spectrum
$MPin$.  However, it doesn't say how many copies of them actually show up.  To find it out, you have to refer to the paper ["Structure of Spin Cobordism Ring"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970690?uid=3738016&uid=2481646813&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21104367554033) by the same authors, Theorem 2.2 (and the definition of $J$'s on the top of the same page).

Thus
$RP^{\infty }\wedge bo\langle 8n\rangle$ appears as many times as the number of the sequences $(j_1,\cdots ,j_k)$, $j_i> 1$, $k\geq 0$ ($k=0$ means
that we have an empty sequence) with $j_1+\cdot +j_k=2n$

and $RP^{\infty }\wedge bo\langle 8n+2\rangle$ appears  as many times as the number of the sequences $(j_1,\cdots ,j_k)$, $j_i> 1$, $k\geq 0$ ($k=0$ means
that we have an empty sequence) with $j_1+\cdots ,+j_k=2n+1$

For the latter here is no such sequence when $n=0$, this is why there is no contribution of $bo\langle -2\rangle$.

As to the case of dimension 22 there will be one copy of $bo\langle 0\rangle$,
one copy of $bo\langle 8\rangle$ and two copies of $bo\langle 16\rangle$ 
(one for the sequence $ (2,2)$ and another for $(4)$) as well as a copy of
$bo\langle 10\rangle$ and two copies of $bo\langle 18\rangle$.  Thus there is no contradiction.

Comment: This helps, thanks. Also $bo<8n-2>$ should be $bo<8n+2>$, and $j_i > 1$ instead of $j_i \geq 1$ right? Otherwise you get 2=2=1+1 so that $bo<8>$ appears twice.

Comment: You are right, I edited the answer.

Comment: Everything works fine up to dimension 10. In dimension 22, seems that we are able to get all factors except $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, it is a bit weird that we get this factor, since it comes from $BO<8n+2>$ in dim 8n+2+i, $i \equiv 6 (8)$, and dim=22 does not lie in this category. $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,n)$ can only contribute a single $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so it cannot be $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,n)$.

Comment: Each copie of $\Sigma ^nHZ/2$ can only contribute a single $Z/2$.  However, there are many copies, and the number of copies is not said explicitely in Theorem 2.2 of  "Structure of Spin Cobordism Ring".  This is why you need to compare with the results for $\pi _*Mspin$